# C# - OCR algorithms

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, ocr

I want to create a small application for windows phone, where the user will take a photo of his electricity bill and the app will get the sum he needs to pay and the user's number.
I read that OCR algorithms can manage it, but have no idea where to start.
can anyone help please?

Comment: for now - just searched algorithms, didn't try as I'm not sure how to start even using it

Answer (score 1):

One popular opinion is to 'outsource' OCR to an existing technology instead of creating or implementing your own algorithms.  Instead, focus on your app and functionality while existing OCR provides you with building blocks  Others spent years focusing on their domain expertise in OCR.  For example, as my college project I chose to implement OCR, which took me a few months and resulted in a system that worked on limited amount of fonts and image variations, not a robust commercial implementation, especially for highly variable mobile images.  This days I use pluggable kits for my OCR needs in apps.

One such OCR on-demand resource is OCR-IT ([www.ocr-it.com](http://www.ocr-it.com)).  It is a cloud-based service that can be called from any app or any code.  Disclaimer: I consult on OCR technology implementation at OCR-IT.  I also used it in many iOS and Android apps I wrote and consulted on.  Quality is top level.

If your goal is to develop the app, outsource such specialty items as OCR or use existing technology kits for more powerful OCR and quicker development cycle.  If you are specifically interested in implementing OCR algorithms for your app, that is an involved and interesting process.  I will be glad to share more information in either case if you'd like.

Ilya Evdokimov

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with neural networks. I have written a [Parallel Neural Network in C#](http://www.igorsevo.com/Article.aspx?article=Parallel%20Neural%20Network%20Library%20%28.NET%20and%20C%2b%2b%29) which you could use.

Check out the following articles for further reading on how to implement this:

- [Applying Neural Networks to Character Recognition](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/feneric/charrecnn.html)
- [Neural Network OCR](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11285/Neural-Network-OCR)